# Error when running a Shiny app with log in form (shinyauthr package): Problem with `filter()` input `..1`. i Input `..1`

Tags: r, dataframe, authentication, shiny, shinyauthr

I have a rather simple Shiny app that consists of a table that reacts to three filters and it works just fine.
However, I need it to have at least a mild layer of security, so I added a Login module with the Shinyauthr package adapting my app code to the one posted in https://github.com/PaulC91/shinyauthr.

The problem is that when I run the app the filters and the table appear and it seems to work fine but still I get the following error:

"Warning: Error in : Problem with `filter()` input `..1`.
i Input `..1` is `conditional(input$selector_destiny != "", Destiny_flight == input$selector_destiny)`.
x argument has length 0."

I've looked at many posts online but since I'm new to Shiny, I'm still unable to figure out what is wrong with my code. Any help solving this issue would be great!

Here is the code for the app with the login form:

```
library(DT)
library(shiny)
library(dplyr) 
library(shinyjs)

#data
my_data <- data.frame(
    "Destiny_flight" = as.character(c("CDB", "OPF", "ABC", "CDB", "OPF")), 
    "Origin" = as.character(c("ABC", "CDB", "CDB", "OPF", "ABC")), 
    "Date_flight" = as.Date(c("2020-01-24", "2021-06-09", "2021-03-19", "2020-12-24", "2021-01-08"),format = "%Y-%m-%d")
)


# dataframe that holds usernames, passwords and other user data
user_base <- tibble::tibble(
    user = c("user1", "user2"),
    password = c("pass1", "pass2"),
    permissions = c("admin", "standard"),
    name = c("User One", "User Two"))

# ui ----
ui <- navbarPage(title = "Title2",
    tabPanel(title = "Title2",
             useShinyjs(), 
             div(class = "container", 
                 div(
                     class = "pull-right", shinyauthr::logoutUI(id = "logout")),
                 shinyauthr::loginUI(id = "login")),
             uiOutput(outputId = "row_input"),
             DTOutput('table_final')))

# Server ----

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    
    # call the logout module with reactive trigger to hide/show
    logout_init <- callModule(
        shinyauthr::logout,
        id = "logout",
        active = reactive(credentials()$user_auth))
    
    # call login module supplying data frame, user and password cols
    # and reactive trigger
    credentials <- callModule(
        shinyauthr::login,
        id = "login",
        data = user_base,
        user_col = user,
        pwd_col = password,
        log_out = reactive(logout_init()))
    
conditional <- function(condition, success) {
        if (condition) success else TRUE}
    
    reactiveDf <- reactive({
        my_data %>%
            dplyr::filter(
                conditional(input$selector_destiny != '', Destiny_flight == input$selector_destiny), 
                Date_flight >= input$dateRange[1] & Date_flight <= input$dateRange[2]
            )
    })
    
#  App ---- 
output$table_final <- renderDT({
    req(credentials()$user_auth)
    reactiveDf() 
})
    
output$row_input <- renderUI({
    req(credentials()$user_auth)
    fluidRow(
             column(width = 6,
                         selectInput(
                             "selector_destiny",
                             label = "Destiny",
                             choices = c('',unique(unlist(my_data$Destiny_flight))),
                             multiple = FALSE, 
                             selectize = TRUE)),
             column(width= 6,
                         dateRangeInput('dateRange',
                                        label = 'Date',
                                        start = as.Date('2020-01-24') , 
                                        end = as.Date('2021-06-09'),
                                        width = '1500%')))
        
    }) 
}
# Run app
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. If you want your problem solved, please remove code that are not relevant to the problem. Check this https://mastering-shiny.org/action-workflow.html#getting-help if you are in doubt.

Comment: I can see the table just fine after logging in!